# discordjs add command files dynamically

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I made discord.js command files, and I want to add command files dynamically
But the source code make some errors, but this source code was operated without errors.

```
        const FilePath = './src/command';
        const commandFileList = fs.readdirSync(FilePath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        if (commandFileList.length) {
            commandFileList.forEach(async (file) => {
                const srcDir = './command/' + file;
                let module;
                await import(srcDir)
                    .then((s) => {
                        module = new s.default();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                this.commands.set(module.name, module);
            });
        }
    }
```

the error message is

```
TypeError: s.default is not a constructor
    at file:///D:/IdeaProjects/discordhrbot/src/client.js:31:34
    at async file:///D:/IdeaProjects/discordhrbot/src/client.js:29:17
file:///D:/IdeaProjects/discordhrbot/src/client.js:36
                this.commands.set(module.name, module);
```

[image]

And the example of command File is following image
[image]

So What Should I do?

Comment: 2 things: can we see an example of a command file? | What do you mean by "dynamically add file"?

Comment: The files in 'src/command' is a command files. The files is the commands and, the source code I wrote is a part adding command files.

Comment: We can see where the command files are located. What we're asking for is what text is contained within those files. Please update your question with some sort of template of your command files.

Comment: I added the example of command files